# jQuery timepicker on custom FAPI form element

Tags: forms, javascript, datetime

How can i add jQuery timepicker to custom form element. There is some description on API docs:

> #date_time_callbacks: An array of optional callbacks for the time >element. Can be used to add a jQuery timepicker or an 'All day' >checkbox.
> https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21Element%21Datetime.php/function/Datetime%3A%3AprocessDatetime

But i can't find any working example to do this.
If the form element looks for example like this:

```
  $form = array(
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#default_value' => new DrupalDateTime('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
  '#date_date_element' => 'date',
  '#date_time_element' => 'none',
  '#date_year_range' => '2010:+3',
  '#date_timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
);
```

Comment: Thank you for asking. There are several ways to implement this including non-code  and code options. I haven't checked for duplicates here, but there may be an existing answer somewhere with terms like "date_popup" or "javascript behavior" or "attached". Reviewing the Drupal JavaScript documentation on drupal.org should help as well for a code answer.